# Does the Polish character Ł have an established mathematical meaning

Tags: notation

I was suggested to use the slashed letter $\L$ (the European character Ł, which looks like the English letter L with a small bar crossing its vertical part) to denote the left half-plane. To avoid conflict with possible common usage, could someone tell me other usages of this notation in mathematics please?

Comment: Do you mean the Polish "dark l"?

Comment: Yes I do. Any ideas?

Comment: I've not seen this used for anything at all within mathematics. However, in the U.S. at least, people are not so aware of the Polish letter, and will therefore have trouble reading this. In particular, how would you expect people to say it out loud? "w" (in English)? "Funny-ell"? "L-slash"? Then "why is it slashed?". Can't a math-italic or math-blackboard-bold serve your needs?

Comment: I haven't seen $\L$ used in math. But a larger issue is whether you're also planning to use $L$ (unslashed) for something else. If so, then you'll confuse a lot of your readers. If not, then by all means, use $\L$ if you want, although just using $L$ would work as well. (Or, as suggested by Paul, use $\mathbb L$, or possibly $\mathcal L$, although the latter suggests a line bundle or sheaf.) There's also fraktur, since many people use $\frak H$ for the upper half-plane, you could use $\frak L$ for the left half-plane.)

Comment: It is commonly used to denote the Łukasiewicz multivalued logic, as well as the Łukasiewicz t-norm.

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion/advice you were given. It would seem more sensible to use ${\mathbb L}$. Moreover, using the Polish letter is incorrect since we are not talking about the Weft Half-Plane ...

Comment: All this talk about the Polish letter and half planes is reminding me of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/1ttuf4/a_polish_man_is_forced_to_take_the_controls_in_of/) // Anyway, if you are working in the setting of complex analysis, you could also just use $i \mathbb{H}$ or $i \mathfrak{H}$ depending on which is your preferred way to write the upper half plane. // It would probably be helpful to specify your field/intended audience. Math notation is overloaded enough as it is, but I doubt your use of left-half-plane will be in a paper that also addresses fuzzy logic.

Comment: Many people use $\mathbb{C}_-$, which is pretty suggestive for the left half plane.

Comment: A good use of $\L$ (though I have never seen this notation) is to denote the set of all Łukasiewicz words (http://oeis.org/wiki/%C5%81ukasiewicz_words).

Comment: @RichardStanley Thanks Richard! Found it from Page 205 of your book EC2.

Comment: Łhy not?$\phantom\l\!\!\!$

Comment: What about $\displaystyle Ł:={L\over2\pi}$ ?